# Connecting AWS Glue to Mongodb Atlas Cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

Has anyone ever managed to get this to work? I've added a connection in AWS Glue to connect to my Mongodb cluster in Atlas but experiencing

`Check that your connection definition references your Mongo database with correct URL syntax, username, and password Exiting with error code 30`

in aws.

I spun up an ec2 instance in the same subnet as the glue connection in my VPC and it connects just fine. Also allowed all traffic in my security group but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you followed published documentation, reference it and what you've done. If you haven't, follow published documentation.

Comment: Having the exact same problem and have tried the same thing.

Comment: @SeanK - AWS have known issues with this. my mongodb version on atlas is 3.6 - and there is a problem with the SSL (something to do with a conflicting trust store on the policy) I never got mine working - but you should maybe try using a jdbc connection string and also make sure to use authSource as mentioned below in case you are authing with a separate database. Also make sure you're connecting to the primary shard and leave out the +srv if your connection string uses mongo+srv protocol

Comment: @JohnM were you able to find the solution for this. I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might gotta take a look at `authSource` for optional compositions in a string uri of MongoDB.

### Scala Example

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.MappingSpec
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.errors.CallSite
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object GlueApp {
  val DEFAULT_URI: String = "mongodb://<an_ip_from_atlas_project_ip_access_list>:27017"
  val WRITE_URI: String = "mongodb://<an_ip_from_atlas_project_ip_access_list>:27017"
  lazy val defaultJsonOption = jsonOptions(DEFAULT_URI)
  lazy val writeJsonOption = jsonOptions(WRITE_URI)
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)

    // Get DynamicFrame from MongoDB
    val resultFrame: DynamicFrame = glueContext.getSource("mongodb", defaultJsonOption).getDynamicFrame()

    // Write DynamicFrame to MongoDB and DocumentDB
    glueContext.getSink("mongodb", writeJsonOption).writeDynamicFrame(resultFrame)

    Job.commit()
  }

  private def jsonOptions(uri: String): JsonOptions = {
    new JsonOptions(
      s"""{"uri": "${uri}",
         |"database":"test",
         |"collection":"coll",
         |"username": "username",
         |"password": "pwd",
         |"ssl":"true",
         |"ssl.domain_match":"false",
         |"partitioner": "MongoSamplePartitioner",
         |"partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB": "10",
         |"partitionerOptions.partitionKey": "_id"}""".stripMargin)
  }
}
```

*You maybe need to assign the authentication source as a database in the cluster you intend to connect.*
`mongodb://<an_ip_from_atlas_project_ip_access_list>:27017?authSource=test`

### References

1. docs.atlas.mongodb.com. 2021. *Connect to a Cluster*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster.
2. docs.aws.amazon.com. 2021. *Examples: Setting Connection Types and Options*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-samples.html.
3. docs.mongodb.com. 2021. *Configuration Options*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration#partitioner-conf.
4. docs.mongodb.com. 2021. *Connection String URI Format*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/.